# Add "duplicates list edited" to viewable actions in profile

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions, profile-page

One of the privileges associated with a gold tag badge is the ability to modify the list of duplicate questions shown when a question has been closed as a duplicate.

I edited a duplicate list on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48119979/revisions) a few minutes ago, and I just realized I don't see a good path back to it from my profile. I found it again easily enough because I had commented on it, but that won't always be the case, and that isn't a reliable way to do it anyway, considering the impermanence of comments.

My feature request is to list those edits somewhere in the profile. Maybe they could be shown under the "all actions" or "votes" section.

In the meantime, does someone know of another way to query those? Or is it already there somewhere and I just missed it?

Comment: Seems like this should show up under "votes" -> "closure"? Good idea.

Comment: Oh yeah, votes would make sense too. I was thinking of it as an edit, but I guess it's like another close vote.

Comment: I couldn't even find the related records in SEDE. `PostLinks` contains a list of *current* duplicates, but `PostHistory` does only contain the initial closure event (at least, when I checked for [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/360663/revisions)).

Comment: @Glorfindel does that mean that currently, duplicates list editions are anonymous/untraceable?

Comment: @Cœur Duplicate list edits show up in the post history attributed to the user who made the change, so it's certainly not anonymous, and it's presumably somehow traceable by someone, because the information is *somewhere* (even if we don't have access to it).

Comment: @Dukeling so, add it to the data dump?

Comment: What is "a duplicate list on a question"? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the "Actions" page to be fully consistent, I agree that we could include this information... but, as-is, I believe the conceivable use-cases for this feature are relatively small. While it may from time to time be convenient, the impact is not big enough for us to prioritize this work — as such I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)ing it. If it becomes a more urgent or pertinent issue, have a look at the guidance [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/208518) on how to put this on our radar again.

If you suspect someone is abusing this privilege, please flag it for mod or staff attention. We can investigate manually as needed, and also reassess the request then.